# Christian claims God spoke to bibilical prophets but never to Mohammad. Is it true?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, islamic-basis, christianity, bible

"God spoke to Biblical prophets but never to Mohammad"

(Gen 8:15 God spoke to Noah, Gen 24:7 to Abraham, Gen 31:11 to Jacob, Exo 6:2 to Moses, 1Sam 3:17 to Samuel, 2Sam 23:3 to David, etc...)

**DISCLAIMER**: The above statement is posted by a Christian, not me. He held these prove steadily against Islam as the truth.

Comment: So what are his proofs that God didn't speak to Muhammad? Simply quoting the bible isn't enough. Exactly what kind of answer are you looking for?

Answer (score 2):

God talked **directly** to Moses and didn't do this with any other prophet (except Prophet Mohamad PBUH).

Many verses in the Qur'an support this. Example:

> Your companion [Muhammad] has not strayed, nor has he erred,
>   Nor does he speak from [his own] inclination.
>   **It is not but a revelation revealed,** [53:(2..4)](http://tanzil.net/#53:10)

Another one:

> And he revealed to His Servant what he revealed.[53:10][2]

In addition, Allah spoke to His Prophet directly at al-Israa Wal Miraaj, and even though the details aren't narrated in the Qu'ran, we have many hadiths that talk about it and how did he talk to him.

Answer (score 0):

It is evident reading the Quran that the Prophet Muhammadﷺ does not only speak in the name of God but that he is telling the Word of God as he has heard and understood it.

Those who do not believe him will not accept this, saying it only testifies itself.

But also the Torah testifies itself because it is the only ancient source stating that what is contained in it is the message God gave to Moses (or to Abraham and his successors before him).

If they only accept the Bible: Of course it can not testify that God spoke to Muhammadﷺ because all the Bible has been written before.

Quran 2:89

> And how are they behaving now towards a Book which has come to them
> from Allah? Inspite of the fact that it confirms the Scriptures which
> they already possessed. and, inspite of the fact that, before it came,
> they used to pray for a signal victory over the disbelievers, they
> rejected it when it came, although they recognized it.

But if they do not accept the Quran, they can accept this ;-)

Quran 5:47

> So let the people of the Gospel rule according to what God revealed in
> it. Those who do not rule according to what God revealed are the
> sinners.